# What is the difference between "not ==" and "!="?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators, equality

I was looking at google, but I could not find an answer.

```
if 5 != 10:
    print('True')

# True

if not 5 == 10:
    print('True')

# True
```

Both seem to do the same. When to use "not ==" and when to use "!="?

Comment: They're not similar at all: `!=` is a binary operator, `not` is a unary operator. What's similar is `a != b` vs `not (a == b)`. The question is similar to "When do you use `True` and when do you use `not False`?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of a comparison with two integers, they are the same.  Prefer `!=` as more pythonic.

The result may differ if *either* operand is an instance of a custom class.  Custom classes are free to override `==` and `!=` operator independently (even with insane results)

From the LHS:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return False
...     def __ne__(self, other):
...         return False
...     
>>> a = A()
>>> a != 5
False
>>> not a == 5
True
```

From the RHS:

```
>>> class R(str):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return False
...     def __ne__(self, other):
...         return False
...     
>>> r = R()
>>> 'spam' != r
False
>>> not 'spam' == r
True
```

Answer (score 4):

These statements are equivalent as long as `==` returns the logical inverse of `!=`. For most data types this is a valid assumption, however Python allows to implement `==` and `!=` specifically ([`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) for `==` and [`__ne__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__) for `!=`). So it really depends on the data type you're using.

And `==` and `!=` may not even return booleans, they don't even have to return the same data type. Which opens up another possibility to customize the result: Via [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), which can be customized (besides others) by the [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) (or `__nonzero` in Python 2) method.

However for integers both of your approaches are equivalent. However I would always use the `!=` approach. It's clearer about the intent and shorter.

Just to give you an example where the statements are not equivalent, let's take a data type such as NumPy arrays (just to name a popular data structure that implements the operators differently) that implements `==` and `!=` to return another NumPy array containing booleans and also implements `__bool__` to throw an Exception:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([1,2,3]) != np.array([3,3,3])
array([ True,  True, False])

>>> not np.array([1,2,3]) == np.array([3,3,3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

But if you used any of these in an `if` both would raise the Exception.

Comment: `__bool__` is for conversion to a boolean value, the result of which can then be subjected to logical negation by `not`. `__bool__` does not actually implement `not`.

Comment: @GilHamilton Well `__bool__` is the most direct way of implementing the [truth value](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) of an instance. I mean yeah, technically you can also implement it via `__len__` but that's probably totally beyond the question. I probably should have said that "`not` checks the "truth value", which could be implemented via `__bool__`". :)

Comment: I still think your answer is conflating two different things: `__bool__` implements truth value determination. `not` simply negates an existing boolean value. Hence there is no special method on an object to "implement `not`" -- whereas there *is* such a special method for `!=`

Comment: @GilHamilton Okay, now I'm slightly confused: `not` will *explicitly* call `__bool__` (if it's implemented), it doesn't need a boolean. That's why you can use `not 10` and such like. On the other hand `!=` could also be implemented by `__eq__` if `__ne__` is not implemented. If we go into all the finer points about this is gets very complicated. Long story short: I think it's a good "rule of thumb" that one can use `__bool__` to implement truth value testing, including `not` (even if it's not 100% correct - but it's probably 99% correct).

Comment: The conversion to a boolean value is what causes the call to `__bool__` and it happens first (before `not` is evaluated). In other words, `if not 10` works because it's equivalent to `if not bool(10)` -- it's just that the boolean conversion is implicit in the former. But you can also do `if 10` which is implicitly converted to `if bool(10)`.

Comment: @GilHamilton Ah I think I know what you mean. However an `if` statement also does the implicit boolean conversion, so it's really `if bool(not bool(10))` and `if bool(10)`. But I updated the answer a bit to make it more obvious that it's customizing the truth value not customizing `not` and only in case `==` and `!=` return types that implement these differently. Thank you for your comments. :)

Answer (score -2):

As you can see with the outcome, both mean the same thing, checking if one value is different from the other, it's a matter of preference...